# How to apply regex search on value of object if keys are random in mangodb.?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions

Following is a sample document from my collection. I need to regex search the value list of each item in "`variations`" object and return all the matching item as a list.

```
{  

   "sample_id":2
   "variations":{  
          "camel":[  
             "caml",
             "caamel"         
          ],
          "camera":[  
             "camra",
             "caamera"
          ],

       }
    }
```

For example if my search term is "`cam`" then query should return `["caml", "camra]`, if my search term is "`caa`" it should return `["caamel", "caamera"]`. How can I achieve this using `mongodb aggregate query method`.